# pyspark mllib explainedVariance for linear regression

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I have a regression linear simple model with 0,84 r2.
how can I interpret the output of this function explainedVariance is 155

```
explainedVariance = 1 - variance(y - \hat{y}) / variance(y)
```

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/ml/regression/LinearRegressionSummary.html#explainedVariance()

What is the meaning of **\hat{y}** is the prediction?

```
def explainedVariance(self):
    """
    Returns the explained variance regression score.
    explainedVariance = 1 - variance(y - \hat{y}) / variance(y)
    """
    return self.call("explainedVariance")
```

Comment: 155 is that correct?

Comment: yes it is the output for my model

Comment: i had the impression it was 0 to 1 or negative only. mmm

Comment: try statsexchange